Are the array fields advanced filters supported on Go SDK?
The advanced filters described in this document: https://milvus.io/docs/array_data_type.md (ARRAY_CONTAINS, ARRAY_CONTAINS_ALL, ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY, and ARRAY_LENGTH) require a filter field in the arguments of client.search or client.query. I don't see this filter argument in the search and query source code.
    Search(ctx context.Context, collName string, partitions []string,
        expr string, outputFields []string, vectors []entity.Vector, vectorField string, metricType entity.MetricType, topK int, sp entity.SearchParam, opts ...SearchQueryOptionFunc) ([]SearchResult, error)

    Query(ctx context.Context, collectionName string, partitionNames []string, expr string, outputFields []string, opts ...SearchQueryOptionFunc) (ResultSet, error)

I see we can add them as part of expr but they do not work as intended. e.g ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY(x, y) doesn't return true for rows where some elements in x exist in y. Though it works when y only has a single element.

The expr parameter is a string used for filtering, and all SDKs use the same expression syntax for this purpose.
For advanced filtering with ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY, you can refer to the examples provided in the Milvus documentation: https://milvus.io/docs/array_data_type.md#Advanced-filtering
Assume there is an Array field named color_coord in a collection. For instance, a row might be inserted as:
{"id": xxx, "vector": [xxxx], "color_coord": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

To filter using ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY, the expression should be:
expr="ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY(color_coord, [1, 3, 5])"

